# creating a html table dynamically and display the record which is store in the database

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on json  in javascript. I am creating a html table dynamically and display the record which is stored in the database with the help of the json object length. But I have an issue I am unable to decide the  number of a column based on the value store in a particular row.

Can anybody help me out on this issue. Mean How to decide number of the column while the value coming from database.

For Example :

for Row ---  I am doing like this:

```
for ( var i =0;i<ob.length:i++){ 
      AddHTML +="<tr>"      
      // for column
      for( var j=0;j<=i;j++){
          Addhtml += "<td>" +obj.name + "</td> "; 
      }  
      //like that I am adding column data   
      AddHtml +="</tr>" ;  
 }
```

But at the end of the row it added one duplicate row  how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link and correct the formatting of your question. When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box next to the text area, a toolbar above the text area with lots of useful tools, a **[?]** icon to give you more help if you needed it, and a  preview area underneath the text box showing you exactly what your question would look like when posted. When asking for help, take the time to make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: try using [jquery](http://jquery.com/) for interacting with the dom from javascript. There you have an [each method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), and you can iterate over your json object and add div rows accordingcly

Comment: are you using asp.net ?

Comment: how does your object look like?

Comment: I am using asp.net and my table look like a HTML table ,but at the end it added duplicate row .How to solve this issue.

Comment: I need to write the code in java Script only.....

Comment: My object look like a normal HTML Table.....